# How to solve $\int{ \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{ m }{ { a }^{ 2 }- { x }^{ 2 } } } }~\mathrm{d} x$

Tags: integration, conic-sections

> $$\int{  \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{ m  }{ { a  }^{ 2  }- { x  }^{ 2  }    }    }    }~\mathrm{d} x.$$
> $m$ and $a$ are both constants and I have already simplified $m$ and $a$ all the way.  And I can't simplify it anymore.
> Is this integration even possible? My calculator just shows a math error.

I saw that an ellipse didn't have any formula for its circumference and so I wanted to try making a formula for the circumference of an ellipse using some calculus.
Here, $m = ((ba)^2)/(a^2-b^2)$

Where $a$ and $b$ are the two radius of the ellipse
There are some other constants but I was able to put it outside the integration and so this is the only part that I don't know how to proceed further with.

I personally don't think that this integration is possible cause if it was then people way smarter than me would've already calculated a formula for the circumference already. But I still wanted to try anyway.

The starting integral is
$$2 \int{  \sqrt{  \frac{ b  ^ { 2  }  x  ^ { 2  }    }{ a  ^ { 2  }  (a  ^ { 2  }  -x  ^ { 2  }  )  }  +1   }    }\,d x   $$

I got this starting integral using the formula of an ellipse and the formula for the length of a graph

Comment: Can you show what simplification you ended up with?

Comment: @RalphClausn  Please do not add displaystyle to titles, nor use both double dollar signs **and** displaystyle.

Comment: Sahil, if you posted your "simplified" integral, then you need to add the original integral, in case your work in simplification had errors.

Comment: You tried to find the length of an arc of ellipse. This lead to elliptic integrals. The name has an obvious origin.

Comment: You heard right. There is no elementary formula. Why did you expect this integral to have a nice result?

Answer (score 1):

This smells like an Elliptic integral... Let's see.

Call $$x = a\sin(p) ~~~~~ \text{d}x = a\cos(p)\ \text{d}p$$

The integral becomes

$$\int \sqrt{1 - \frac{m}{a^2\cos^2(p)}}\ a\cos(p)\ \text{d}p$$

Which can be easily arranged like

$$a\int \sqrt{\cos^2(p) - \beta}\ \text{d}t ~~~~~~~ \beta \equiv \frac{m}{a^2}$$

The result of this is indeed an Elliptic integral:

$$a\frac{\sqrt{-2 \beta+\cos (2 p)+1} \color{red}{E\left(p\left|\frac{1}{1-\beta}\right.\right)}}{\sqrt{-\frac{-2 \beta+\cos (2 p)+1}{\beta-1}}}$$

Consider that being $\beta$ unknown, we can simplify the previous result iff $\beta < 1$ which would yield

$$\sqrt{1 - \beta}\color{red}{E\left(p\left|\frac{1}{1-\beta}\right.\right)}$$

You can pullback to $p\to x$ easily now.

As I smelled, $\color{red}{\text{Elliptic integral}}$.

More on Elliptic integrals here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral